# Approximate eigenvectors of complex value eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

I was studying some basic theory to approximate differential equations near their fixed points and some question regarding eigenvectors and eigenvalues occurred to me, here it is:

If you have $2\times 2$ square matrix with real entries and it has complex eigenvalues, is it possible to take the real part of its eigenvalues and find approximate eigenvectors with it? I have been searching for a theorem that can guarantee me that, but have not found it. Thanks in advance for the time taken to read the question. (Assume the matrix is non-symmetric with a trace different than 0.)

Comment: In general, this will never work for any matrix with pure imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero the assumption at the end of the question precludes purely imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: Anyway, the real part of both non-real eigenvalues of the $2\times2$ matrix described is exactly half its trace.